# Is it a good solution for private data transmission and protection?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I wish to build a private data transmission and protection scheme for user login function on my website. The private data I wish to protect is the user id and the password.

My requirements for this scheme include: Secure data transmission (without SSL, TCL), highly safe storage (once lose password, data becomes sort of unrecoverable)

I have drafted one listed below:

1. RSA (encryption and decryption on client and server sites respectively)
   In detail, I plan to use Javascript to encrypt user id and password on the client site, and PHP to generate private &　public keys and decrypt the received cipher text on the server site.
2. SHA256/SHA512/Twice MD5 (on server site, encryption using random Salt which is bidden with user ID)
   Using PHP to re-encrypt the plain password with SHA256 algorithm with a user id binding salt.

Is this a good solution to meet my requirement? thanks

Comment: Secure data transmission without SSL / TLS - how? Encrypting trough JS? How is that secure? Lose password, lose all the data? Wtf? Why would anyone use such a service?

Comment: You might also try asking at http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: "without SSL, TCL" is never a sane requirement for a system wanting to securely transmit data over HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to make sure your password can't be intercepted, ist to not transmit it: This is much easier than one might think:

- On the server side, store the passowrds salted and hashed (There are thousands of articles on how to do this properly)
- When a user on the client logs in, he inputs username and password
- With the username, request the salt from the server (e.g. via AJAX). This is not a security problem, as the salt is not secret. In the same reply send the server timestamp.
- On the client create the salted hash, this results in a secret, that both parties know, even if it never has crossed the wire. Keep it.
- Use the server timestamp and the client local time to calculate a time offset and keep it - you will need it to avoid replay attacks.
- You can now use this secret (salted password hash) and the timestamp to securely transmit whatever you want: For a request, salt the passhash with the (offset-corrected) timestamp and some entropy, hash again. Use this as a key to encrypt (AES comes to mind) your message to the server, sending the timestamp and random salt along
- On the server reject timestamps older than a few seconds to be replay safe
- On the server use the provide timestamp and salt to recreate the key for this message

Crypto-js has the JS parts you need

Comment: thanks but there are two issues we should not ignore. 1) why transmitting the salt will not result in security problem. i mean once someone obtain the salt which we used for the salted password hass, the salt seems to be transparent for recovering the passhash with brute force. The reason for using RSA in my solution is that the leakage of public key is not a security problem.

Comment: 2) AES using the same key for encryption and decryption, isn't it. If so, will the transmission of timestamp and salt which will be used as the key incur security issues?  Assuming the hacker can access the source code for encryption and decryption.

Comment: 1) Read up on salting: Salt is not secret, it is a defence against precompution attacks (e.g. rainbow tables). 2.) Both sides use the same key, but it is never transmitted, which makes it sort of hard to intercept it. If the browser is compromised you don't need to think about encryption: In this case the cleartext password is compromised also.

Comment: >Salt is not secret, it is a defence against precompution attacks, yes but once you get salt and the salted password, dont you think the salt can be used for decryption?

Comment: Just read up on that: Having a random salt, even if it is completly public, means, that the hash has to be reversed without the help of precomputed tables. This means, that not **one** precomputation effort can be used for **all** passwords. The salt alone can't be used for decryption.

Answer (score 0):

And a bad news for us :(  RSA 1024 bit was cracked in 100 hours! Here is the article:

[1024-bit RSA encryption cracked by carefully starving CPU of electricity](http://www.engadget.com/2010/03/09/1024-bit-rsa-encryption-cracked-by-carefully-starving-cpu-of-ele/)